# Sprites saved in INA and AN format?

Tags: tools, sprites

I'm not sure if this is a suitable question but I found a game that had all it is sprites and stuff saved in INA and AN format and I got curious to know which program is it.

Or is it some sort of compressing or alike and how it is usually done?

Anyone know?

Here is the content of one of the files: 
http://pastebin.com/EzUsFvdG

Here is a hex dump of the above file: http://pastebin.com/CTErFBcS

The above one is the AN file and the bellow one INA.

Hex dump of a INA file which seems to be some sort of map or data file (I believe because of the layers info, etc?) http://pastebin.com/2fWn8izR

Comment: Might be helpful to check the first 4 bytes of the file in case its some normal format with a custom extension.

Comment: When showing an unknown file format it might be more useful to show a [hex dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump)

Comment: The AN file converted from bin to hex http://paste.pocoo.org/show/240671/

Comment: thanks i figured how to hex dump already eheh but still havent figure what the files are :P

Comment: Yeah, I did some digging but I can't find anything on either one. What game is this? Maybe that will provide a clue (or at least a vintage).

Comment: i found it while looking for character sprites at http://untamed.wild-refuge.net/rmxpresources.php?characters following links within the images there... but i will have to look on my history to find out the exctly website but it was either japanese or chinese ... but the images looked good so i ownloaded it to take a look at...

Comment: found it, http://www.mixmaster.co.kr/

Comment: I think I have to throw in the towel, too much of the site is in Flash or images for Google Translate to help >_< Chances are it's something custom from the look of things though.

Comment: The hex dump for the AN file is actually a binary dump. Will be harder to see a pattern in a binary dump than in a he dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, the evidence points towards this being a custom file format specific to that game. Probably not going to be able to open them yourself. However, if it uses OpenGL or DirectX and loads them as textures you might be able to use a GPU memory viewer to dump them to standard format.

Comment: Thanks :) i will take a look at it... could you perhaps recommend me any GPU viewer

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily a common program's output at all. It could just be an arbitrary extension chosen by the developer for files that hold data about sprites. You can try opening the file in notepad to see its contents or as suggested above check the first four bytes to see if it is a normal file format saved under a different extensions.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i've updated my main question with the file content and a hex dump i am kinda of clueless on how to verify it i do know that some files in it is content some times shows for example "Adobe Photoshop" etc ... but this files doesnt give me much ...

Answer (score 0):

A first thing to do would be to display it in various widths to see if any width shows a somewhat recognizable pattern (and humans are extremely good at detecting patterns, even if they're not there). If you're that lucky you'll have a good starting point as you know the likely width and can see if you see that encoded somewhere. From there you can also find height and so on.
Only if there's a discenrable pattern to begin with through. It might be run length encoded or what have you and it'll become pretty tricky pretty fast.

Comment: no idea at all i've went thru it but can't figure it out at all.

Comment: It might help if you mention the game

Comment: the game is mixmaster.co.kr as i said in the comments of the question... thanks ;)